# Homoparental Adoption Studies

Tags: social-psychology

Such as the [World Professional Association for Transgender Health](https://www.wpath.org/), which involves a relative large group of professional for concluding about *Transgender* protocols and studies, and somehow unrelated but such as the [National Academies of Sciences, Engineering and Medicine](http://www.nationalacademies.org/hmd/Reports.aspx), is there some neutral organization involving Systematic Reviews of studies concluding about the effects -rather positive and|or negative- about *Homoparental Adoption*?

The most comprehensive reference I have found is a paper from [Schofield 2016](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1053&context=hdfs_pubs) which summarizes 81 studies. But this paper is still a single person document, which perfectly could be subject to an author bias.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, I've thought about this myself. However, I doubt that there will be any large causal effects--either negative or positive--since parental effects appear, in general, to be quite weak.

Comment: Yes, I am mostly convinced the conclusion is no difference, but i am still looking for a solid and neutral reference stating this conclusion, or the proper conclusion up to date if positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technical report by the Committee on Psychosocial Aspects of Child and Family Health at the American Academy of Pediatrics ([Perin et al, 2002](https://doi.org/10.1542/peds.109.2.341)) which looks at all the scientific literature concerning homoparental upbringing, and they concluded that:

> The small and nonrepresentative samples studied and the relatively young age of most of the children suggest some reserve. However, the weight of evidence gathered during several decades using diverse samples and methodologies is persuasive in demonstrating that there is no systematic difference between gay and nongay parents in emotional health, parenting skills, and attitudes toward parenting. No data have pointed to any risk to children as a result of growing up in a family with 1 or more gay parents. Some among the vast variety of family forms, histories, and relationships may prove more conducive to healthy psychosexual and emotional development than others.

They also concluded that:

> Although gay and lesbian parents may not, despite their best efforts, be able to protect their children fully from the effects of stigmatization and discrimination, parents’ sexual orientation is not a variable that, in itself, predicts their ability to provide a home environment that supports children’s development.

### References

Perrin, E. C., & Committee on Psychosocial Aspects of Child and Family Health. (2002). Technical report: coparent or second-parent adoption by same-sex parents. *Pediatrics, 109*(2), 341-344. doi: [10.1542/peds.109.2.341](https://doi.org/10.1542/peds.109.2.341)

Comment: Thanks for your reference. At this moment, I think is the most comprehensive reference is [Schofield 2016](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1053&context=hdfs_pubs), which also includes a reference from Perrin 2012. Though the study involved 19 professionals credited in the paper, it still have the taste to be a one person in charge paper (Perrin), and unlike Schofield 2016, it is much less compehensive. I am looking for something more committee fashioned like the WPATH or NASEM reports...

Comment: ...Truly the conclusion is about to be the same, but because of the vast sea of independent studies -some biased and commited to an specific result- I would like to find a bias proof report. Perhaps this simply do not exist. Also this report is from the 2002, which left out 17 years of updates.

Comment: @Brethlosze How do you expect to find a report that is immune to bias? It is up to you to read a report and evaluate the claims relative to the data.